# Loop an array with form

Tags: php, html, arrays

i'm working on some code it seems im stuck... anyone can fix the right source code for looping array form?

```
<pre>
<form action='' method='POST'>
<input type='text' name='jml'>
<input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>

<form action='' method='POST'>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['jml'])){
    $jml = $_POST['jml'];
    for($i=0;$i<$jml;++$i){
?>
    Stuff Name <input type="text" name="name">&nbsp
    Stuff Price <input type='text' name='price'><br>
    <br>
<?php
}
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit2'>";
echo "</form>";
}
if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
    $name[] = $_POST['name'];
    $price[] = $_POST['price'];
    global $jml;
    for($i=0;$i<$jml;++$i){
        echo $name.' '.$price.'<br>';
    }
}
?>
</pre>
```

i was basic at C++ it's so easy to loop, but i'm still much to learn on this php so anyone can help me please?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What doesn't work at the moment?

Comment: this: `$name[] = $_POST['name'];` doesn't make sense here, as you're not in a loop. `$name = $_POST['name'];` will do. And `$jml` wont be an array anyway. It's not clear what you're trying to do here!?

Comment: the name and price variable array from input tag doesn't output the value... i want it to output

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do first is if you're expecting multiple row fields, put a `[]` in your name attribute in text fields. Example:

```
<input type="text" name="name[]">
```

This in turn will accept multiple text inputs under the same name turning it into an array.

Next, since you're reliant on the number of fields to be generated by `$jml = $_POST['jml'];` this will just be available on the first request. On the next submission this will be gone. Instead of using that with a `global` which doesn't make sense, just use the `count` of the submitted text fields.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$count = count($name); // get count
```

Take not that this is reliant to the forms all fields being complete.

After that, its just basic array pointing. `echo $name[$i]`:

Revised code:

```
<pre>
<form action='' method='POST'>
<input type='text' name='jml'>
<input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>

<form action='' method='POST'>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['jml'])){
    $jml = $_POST['jml'];
    for($i=0;$i<$jml;++$i){
?>
    Stuff Name <input type="text" name="name[]">&nbsp
    Stuff Price <input type='text' name='price[]'><br>
    <br>
<?php
}
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit2'>";
echo "</form>";
}
if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $count = count($name);
    for($i=0;$i<$count;++$i){
        echo $name[$i].' '.$price[$i].'<br>';
    }
}
?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `foreach` loop This is how you can easily loop through an array:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
  echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this

> Working code here http://main.xfiddle.com/7ffb488b/stackoverflow/Loopanarraywithform.php

```
<pre>
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo "<form action='' method='POST'>";
    $jml = intval($_POST['jml']);
    for($i=0;$i<$jml;++$i){
?>
    Stuff Name <input type="text" name="name[]">&nbsp
    Stuff Price <input type='text' name='price[]'><br>
    <br>
<?php
}
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit2'>";
echo "</form>";
}elseif(isset($_POST['submit2'])){  
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    //   global $jml;
    $i=0;
    foreach ($name as $key => $value) {
        echo $value.' '.$price[$key].'<br/>';
        $i++;
    }
}else{?>

<form action='' method='POST'>
<input type='text' name='jml'>
<input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>
    <?php
     }
?>
</pre>
```